# Text overflow ellipsis and expand does not work

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a simple code here:

```js
$(".container article").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("expand");
})
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.container article {
  height: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: #5E585B;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.container article.expand {
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <article class="text">
    text text text
  </article>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SqJ53/262/

I need to have a dynamic width and height but ellipsis doesn't work.
Do you guys have any idea without changing the width and height?
I tried setting white-space: nowrap. It shows the ellipsis but removes the expand effect when I click the container.

Comment: No that's not it. I already check it.

Comment: you need the nowrap for the ellipsis - just remove it in your expand class by adding `white-space:normal`

Answer (score 2):

I believe this does what you need. CSS is documented.
More on `text-overflow` and its requirements [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)

```js
$(".container article").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("expand");
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.container article {
  height: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  display: block;
  word-break: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: #5E585B;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* Added. This is required for ellipsis */
}

.container article.expand {
  height: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  /* Added to reset */
  white-space: initial;
  /* Added to reset */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <article class="ITDS">
    MCKY CONT MNGD ITEM MCKY CONT MNGD ITEM MCKY CONT MNGD ITEM MCKY CONT MNGD ITEM MCKY CONT MNGD ITEM MCKY CONT MNGD ITEM MCKY CONT MNGD ITEM MCKY CONT MNGD ITEM MCKY CONT MNGD ITEM MCKY CONT MNGD ITEM MCKY CONT MNGD ITEM MCKY CONT MNGD ITEM MCKY CONT MNGD
    ITEM MCKY CONT MNGD ITEM MCKY CONT MNGD ITEM MCKY CONT MNGD ITEM MCKY CONT MNGD ITEM MCKY CONT MNGD ITEM MCKY CONT MNGD ITEM MCKY CONT MNGD ITEM MCKY CONT MNGD ITEM MCKY CONT MNGD ITEM MCKY CONT MNGD ITEM MCKY CONT MNGD ITEM
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked for me! May I know what does this code do?

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

I ran the code without it and it still worked fine.

Comment: @DevMaker it is the inclusion of jQuery. Without it, "Javascript" part does not work. You had it also in your own code.

Comment: Oh sorry. I have it as well. I have another question. Do you know how to remove the white spaces before the container?

Comment: @DevMaker I have adjusted the code. Most browsers have standard margin/padding for the body which results in the white space.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve text overflow ellipsis using `:after`  by providing `position:relative;` to article and below css class to your css:

```
.container article {
   position:relative;
}
.ITDS:after{
   content: "...";
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   position: absolute;
}
.ITDS.expand:after{
   display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `white-space:nowrap` and keep the word-break properties on the expand section:

```js
$(".container article").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("expand");
})
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.container article {
  height: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  display: block;
  background-color: #5E585B;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  white-space:nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.container article.expand {
  height: auto;
  word-break: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space:normal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <article class="ITDS">
    MCKY CONT MNGD ITEM MCKY CONT MNGD ITEM MCKY CONT MNGD ITEM MCKY CONT MNGD ITEM MCKY CONT MNGD ITEM MCKY CONT MNGD ITEM MCKY CONT MNGD ITEM MCKY CONT MNGD ITEM MCKY CONT MNGD ITEM MCKY CONT MNGD ITEM MCKY CONT MNGD ITEM MCKY CONT MNGD ITEM MCKY CONT MNGD
    ITEM MCKY CONT MNGD ITEM MCKY CONT MNGD ITEM MCKY CONT MNGD ITEM MCKY CONT MNGD ITEM MCKY CONT MNGD ITEM MCKY CONT MNGD ITEM MCKY CONT MNGD ITEM MCKY CONT MNGD ITEM MCKY CONT MNGD ITEM MCKY CONT MNGD ITEM MCKY CONT MNGD ITEM
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: This also worked! But do you know how to remove the white spaces before the container?

Comment: @DevMaker you mean `margin:0` on the body ?